# Infer typescript function arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given the following

```
const action1 = (arg1: string) => {}
const action2 = (arg1: string, arg2: {a: string, b: number}) => {}
const actions = [action1, action2]
handleActions(actions)

... elsewhere ...

const handleActions = (actions: WhatTypeIsThis[]) => {
  const [action1, action2] = actions;
  action1(/** infer string */)
  action2(/** infer string and object */)
}
```

How can I define the `WhatTypeIsThis` type in order for the action args to be inferable inside `handleActions`?

Is it possible to define it in such a way that `actions` can be any number of functions with varying argument lists?

Is it possible using generics?

**My solution:**

I've marked the accepted answer because it was the inspiration for my solution.

```
// get the types of the actions, defined in outer scope
type GET = typeof api.get;
type CREATE = typeof api.create;
...

// in controller
handleActions([api.getSomething, api.create])

...

// in service handler
const handleActions = (actions: [GET, CREATE]) => {
  const [action1, action2] = actions;
  // now we have all input / output type hints
}
```

This approach lets me isolate my logic from the http server, auth, and everything else I didn't write, so I can test the complexity within my service handlers in peace.

Comment: what do you pass into your actions in the `handleActions` function? I assume, that your function is more something like this: `(actions: DesiredType[], ...params: any) => {}`, right?

Comment: @DenisLoh "what do you pass into your actions in the handleActions function?" - I pass the specific arguments that each action takes. Args can be a string, an object full of specific keys, both, and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to define it in such a way that actions can be any number of functions with varying argument lists?

With a *dynamic* list, you need runtime checking. I don't think you can do runtime checking on these functions without branding them (I tried doing it on `length` since those two functions have different lengths, but it didn't work and it really wouldn't have been useful even if it had — `(arg1: string) => void` and `(arg1: number) => void` are different functions with the same `length`).

*With* branding and a runtime check, it's possible:

- Define branded types for the functions
- Create the functions
- Define the action list as an array of a union of the function types
- Have `handleActions` branch on the brand

Like this:

```typscript
type Action1 = (
    (arg1: string) => void
) & {
    __action__: "action1";
};

type Action2 = (
    (arg1: string, arg2: {a: string, b: number}) => void
) & {
    __action__: "action2";
};

const action1: Action1 = Object.assign(
    (arg1: string) => {},
    {__action__: "action1"} as const
);
const action2: Action2 = Object.assign(
    (arg1: string, arg2: {a: string, b: number}) => {},
    {__action__: "action2"} as const
);

const actions = [action1, action2];

type ActionsList = (Action1 | Action2)[];

const handleActions = (actions: ActionsList) => {
    const [action1, action2] = actions;
    if (action1.__action__ === "action1") {
        action1("x");   // <==== infers `(arg: string) => void` here
    }
};  

handleActions(actions);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYEYoF4oAoBQUReAhgE4Dm6AXFAM7BmKoUCU2AfFAG7KIAm+dgDIoAb0LEA+lJIIUqGbQBEcpGnTKA3PgC+O-KEix5aAEzY8kornJVaDJiwA0UO2dpiSDxswquAI1pUAFcAWwCIMl12LC5eASEoUQliKBk1BSUoVVNUM209Azg0Bjc8mhN1DEsAeQCAKwgEADoSOjpEClQCNNtKSsc-WK4xXWdrcQy87NzqzV03OigS1AYhHVWyzPNaeGqLHHqm1vbO7t7ifvt6Xxc3Sg9xb1unfyggqFCIqJjOcXGkzE02qsx2+WUi3aK1KwA2+HwW2A5WqyxwAG1wehXOCzABdAxGaD7BR0AAyiDKOFwJI0UAAPlUFGZWOiCQikVAABYkVD8AA2EFpa0stjydD24opDBG4kmnMxFRxeXxlnBdB0aUQADNSBUWiCslJsFgcHMFJp2Kk0sQsbhlAAPZSsLTEAD0bqgAB5TaaoMxtVFlgADa4+N6yhL8YPcqIQSa6IpEBE8vmC4V0MWol34IA)

---

**Before** you added the text quoted at the top of the answer, it was possible with a readonly [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types). I'm keeping this in the answer in case it's useful to others, even though it doesn't apply to your situation.

Here's what that looks like:

```typescript
type ActionsList = readonly [
    (arg1: string) => void,
    (arg1: string, arg2: { a: string; b: number; }) => void
];
```

To make it readonly, you'll need `as const` on `actions`:

```typescript
const actions = [action1, action2] as const;
//                                ^^^^^^^^^
```

A tuple  is a kind of *"...Array type that knows exactly how many elements it contains, and exactly which types it contains at specific positions."* (from the link above)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhsKBLcBGGBeGAKOAnAc1QC4Zo8kwCBKTAPhgG8BfAbgChRJYFlwAmTDnxFS5SgQA08Qv1KM4YqBSrSARqTABXALZqApnma0MDFhy7R4iFJCEBtXrdTSnAgLrwIMS1A7soAE8AB30YAEEbcAgAGSQrLDx9OAATcAAbQJh7dhg84UISMmUJEwYANxAkFMlc-NxCpRUpGQI5JngmiVYYDRhtPUMe43oYSur2d39fGAALODAU9P1IvjssXCjIUlXbWPioMqY6mcctl2s1-k8sN0gOPLvUbAAiAA8X6g42PPZ2ecWy120U2awgX3YQA)

Comment: Sorry, my question was lacking specifics - I've revised - TLDR: `actions` is a variable length list of different functions

Comment: @James - If the list is dynamic (contents determined at runtime), then you need dynamic checks at runtime. I think you can only do it if you brand the functions. I've updated the answer. :-) *(I don't understand the downvote on the question, BTW, I think it's a reasonable question, and an interesting one.)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't downvote the question, but perhaps the reason it was downvoted is because the OP seems not to want to use a tuple type, but hasn't written a [mcve] where a tuple type wouldn't be the solution, so it's hard to know what they actually want.

Comment: @kaya3 - Fair enough. :-) And I think it was done soon after the change that invalidated my original answer, which might also be a factor.